# Merge 64 Bit and 32 bit android APK as per new android requirement

Tags: android, google-play, apk, adb, 32bit-64bit

We created 64-bit version of my app as per the [android link](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit).

Now we get two folders with 32-bit apk and 64-bit apk which is fine.

Now I want to know, how to merge both this 32/64 bit apk. Is it possible to merge them or we need to upload both 32 bit and 64-bit apk separately in google play store?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can upload two APKs in the same release as long as the **APK targeting 64-bit has a higher version code than the APK targeting 32-bit** (Google Play will complain if you don't do that). All the documentation on this topic can be found at: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks

A simpler alternative is to upload a single **Android App Bundle** in place of an APK, and **Google Play will take care of generating the APKs for each of the native architecture your app supports**. The documentation can be found at: https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

Answer (score 2):

It is ok to have multiple APKs for single app split by resources or NDK libs, because it reduces APKs sizes. You can upload multiple APKs as single app at Android Play Store, it will select appropriate APK for user before installation.

1. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42336433/3858030