# How can I allow lower Android API level users to download my app in a higher API level version?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore, android-api-levels

I am using **Unity** to build an application and there is a part that I applied **ARCore**. However, ARCore only supports devices which have **API level 27 or above**.

I want to build a version which can **also apply in the lower API level devices** because AR is **just one part**  in my whole app.

What I expect the scenario is: not allowing the users which is lower API level 27 to trigger the AR function, but they can **still use** my app.

I am going to release this app to **Google Play Store**. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If the play store supports parallel versions (ie, you build two different projects for the different API levels, then upload under the same store item), I'd do that.  Not sure if that's possible, though.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48556005/342842

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep `minSdkVersion` in your build.gradle file to the one you wish.
2. Add `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="libraryOne|libraryTwo" />` with correct library names (Android Studio's compiler will tell you exact names) to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.
3. Make sure the code requiring higher SDK version is not run on lower SDK versions.